# Can a man in the middle attack stop the data from the receiver?

Tags: ssl, man-in-the-middle

Since an unknown entity will intercept the data communication between two IPs. I have a feeling if he can do such manipulations like stopping the data halfway or even directing it to another IP.

Also, will SSL prevent the unknown entity on intercepting the data or will it just protect the data via encryption?

Comment: Yes, yes, and no.

Comment: @EJP, Thanks for the answer and can you answer in more detail so I can upvote your answer